# Mongoose custom schema type date interval

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have many fields in my documents of type date intervals, such as this

```
{
    publishDate:
    {
       start: {type: Date, required: true},
       end: {type: Date, required: true}
    }
}
```

To reduce duplication of the code and make it easier to maintain, how to create custom Mongoose type, for instance **DateInterval**, containing two fields:

1. **start**
2. **end**

and containing validator that makes sure both fields are filled out, and start is before end?

Answer (score 3):

You can reuse schemas in mongoose.

```
var DateIntervalSchema = new Schema({
   start: {type: Date, required: true},
   end: {type: Date, required: true}
});

var SomeSchema = new Schema({
   publishDate: [DateIntervalSchema],
   // ... etc
});
```

You can also reference documents from other collections.

```
var SomeSchema = new Schema({
   publishDate: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'DateInterval'}
});    

//using populate
SomeModel.findOne({ someField: "value" })
   .populate('publishDate') // <--
   .exec(function (err, doc) {
      if (err) ...

   })
```

Comment: Doesn't the first example declare an **array** DateIntervals, meaning there could be also 0, 2 or lots of intervals in the document?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to develop a custom schema type. There are a number of plugins that do this already, one of which, for long numbers, can be found here: https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-long/blob/master/lib/index.js . This is a good basic example to follow.

For your purposes, then, you can create a `DateInterval` custom schema, casting it as type `Date`, and then use a `validator` to check `start` and `end` - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate.

Comment: This looks interesting, but all custom schema type examples I have seen so far is having one single value, while I'm having two: _start_ and _end_. Not seeing right away how to modify mongoose-long example to support two fields and how to be able to set these two fields when using the model (for instance event.publishDate.start and event.publishDate.end). Any input, @glortho?

Answer (score 0):

Since [mongoose](/questions/tagged/mongoose) >=4.4 you can implement your [custom schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html).

Documentation is not very clear, but you can [follow this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38698581/6386175).

You have to:

- define your `DateInterval` custom object with `toBSON()` / `toJSON()` and `toObject()` prototype methods
- define the `DateIntervalType` inherited from `mongoose.SchemaType` for handle the **mongoose** integration, and casting to `DateInterval`.

In this way you can achieve full control on memory (*Mongoose model*) and mongodb (*raw's bson*) data representation.