# Mongoose advanced custom schema object type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-plugins

I couldn't find any example of an *advanced* [custom schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html) involving custom objects (or [value-objects](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html)) in Mongoose >=4.4.

Imagine that I want to use a custom type like:

```
function Polygon(c) {
  this.bounds = [ /* some data */ ];
  this.npoints = /* ... */
  /* ... initialize polygon ... */
};

Polygon.prototype.area = function surfaceArea() { /**/ };

Polygon.prototype.toObject = function toObject() { return this.bounds; };
```

Next, I implement a custom SchemaType like:

```
function PolygonType(key, options) {
  mongoose.SchemaType.call(this, key, options, 'PolygonType');
}

PolygonType.prototype = Object.create(mongoose.SchemaType.prototype);

PolygonType.prototype.cast = function(val) {
  if (!val) return null;
  if (val instanceof Polygon) return val;
  return new Polygon(val)
}

PolygonType.prototype.default = function(val) {
  return new Polygon(val);
}
```

How can I assure that:

1. Every time a new object is "hydrated" from db (mongoose *init*), I will have a Polygon
   instance and not a plain object. I understand it will use the `cast`
   function. `assert(model.polygon instanceof Polygon)`
2. Every time I will save my Model the Polygon attribute should be
   encoded and stored as a plain object representation
   (`Polygon.prototype.toObject()`) that in this case is an **`Array`** object in mongodb.
3. If I use `model.toObject()` it will recursively call the `model.polygon.toObject()` to have a full plain object representation of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to @vkarpov15 on [github.com](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4356#issuecomment-234798862):

1. `SchemaType.prototype.cast()` is needed to correctly *hydrate* the document model from *raw* mongodb representation, and throw an error in case of invalid data.
2. To customize mongodb persistence, I had to implement a [`toBSON()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_1and2_2.html#tobson-method) function in my custom type object prototype (i.e. `Polygon`).
3. `model.toObject()` / `model.toJSON()` currently doesn't call recursively `toObject()`/`toJSON()` on all children, but it looks like it will be [fixed](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4356#issuecomment-236367135). But I could overload it as temporary workaround assigning a custom `schema.methods.toObject()` instance method.